# Исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException" возникло в bluettoh_ver1.DLL, но не было обработано в коде пользователя

Tags: c#, xamarin, windowsphone

разрабатываю приложение на xamarin,под windows phone 8.1
после компиляции вылетает с ошибкой

- $exception {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  at bluettoh_ver1.App.OnClickStart(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Button.Xamarin.Forms.IButtonController.SendClicked() 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.ButtonRenderer.OnButtonClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}

ругается на

```
private void OnClickStart(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
devices.Clear(); 
seeker.StartSearch(); 
}
```

целиком весь код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace bluettoh_ver1
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        StackLayout layout;
        bool toStart;
        Button buttonStart;
        Button buttonStop;

        ObservableCollection<Info> devices = new ObservableCollection<Info>();
        ISearch seeker;
        public App()
        {
            seeker = DependencyService.Get<ISearch>();

            buttonStart = new Button()
            {
                Text = "Search"
            };
            buttonStop = new Button()
            {
                Text = "Stop",
            };

            buttonStart.Clicked += OnClickStart;
            buttonStop.Clicked += OnClickStop;
            ListView listView = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = devices,

                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    Label nameLabel = new Label();
                    nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

                    Label macLabel = new Label();
                    macLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Mac");

                    return new ViewCell
                    {
                        View = new StackLayout
                        {
                            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                            Children = { nameLabel, macLabel }
                        }

                    };
                })
            };

            layout = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = { buttonStart, buttonStop, listView }
            };

            ContentPage content = new ContentPage
            {
                Title = "Bluetooth Scanner",
                Content = layout
            };

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
        }


        private void OnClickStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            seeker.StopSearch();
        }

        private void OnClickStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            devices.Clear();
            seeker.StartSearch();


        }


        public void AddDevice(Info device)
        {
            devices.Add(device);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `DependencyService.Get<ISearch>();` возвращает `null`

Comment: а можешь подробней описать, как исправить.. не понимаю пока что

Comment: @Denis: Ну, у вас `DependencyService.Get<ISearch>();` возвращает `null`, судя по всему. Вам нужно настроить ваш контейнер зависимостей. Если вы не знаете, что это такое, разберитесь.